# NavigationDrawer does not show fragment pages

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am using a [navigation drawer library](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer).

Now I would like to change the content in the navigation drawer's onClick event. 
But there does not appear anything and I do not get any issue.

How can I achieve that the FragmentManager changes the Fragment successfully?

I have worked already with the navigation drawer before. 
But I never used the coordinator layout. Maybe that's the problem?

main_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.stack.overflow.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_body"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.stack.overflow.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int PROFILE_SETTING = 1;

    private AccountHeader headerResult = null;
    private Drawer result = null;
    private boolean opened = false;
    private Activity mActivity = this;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        final IProfile profile1 = new ProfileDrawerItem().withName("Sample User").withEmail("sample@sample.com").withIcon(R.drawable.ic_starticon).withIdentifier(104);
        final IProfile profile2 = new ProfileDrawerItem().withName("Sample User").withEmail("sample@sample.com").withIcon(R.drawable.ic_starticon).withIdentifier(105);

        headerResult = new AccountHeaderBuilder()
                .withActivity(this)
                .withHeaderBackground(R.drawable.header)
                .addProfiles(
                        profile1,
                        //don't ask but google uses 14dp for the add account icon in gmail but 20dp for the normal icons (like manage account)
                        new ProfileSettingDrawerItem().withName("Add Account").withDescription("Add new GitHub Account").withIcon(new IconicsDrawable(this, GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_plus).actionBar().paddingDp(5).colorRes(R.color.material_drawer_primary_text)).withIdentifier(PROFILE_SETTING),
                        new ProfileSettingDrawerItem().withName("Manage Account").withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_settings)
                )
                .withOnAccountHeaderListener(new AccountHeader.OnAccountHeaderListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onProfileChanged(View view, IProfile profile, boolean current) {
                        //sample usage of the onProfileChanged listener
                        //if the clicked item has the identifier 1 add a new profile ;)
                        if (profile instanceof IDrawerItem && ((IDrawerItem) profile).getIdentifier() == PROFILE_SETTING) {
                            int count = 100 + headerResult.getProfiles().size() + 1;
                            IProfile newProfile = new ProfileDrawerItem().withNameShown(true).withName("Batman" + count).withEmail("batman" + count + "@gmail.com").withIcon(R.drawable.ic_starticon).withIdentifier(count);
                            if (headerResult.getProfiles() != null) {
                                //we know that there are 2 setting elements. set the new profile above them ;)
                                headerResult.addProfile(newProfile, headerResult.getProfiles().size() - 2);
                            } else {
                                headerResult.addProfiles(newProfile);
                            }
                        }

                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .withSavedInstance(savedInstanceState)
                .build();

        result = new DrawerBuilder()
                .withActivity(this)
                .withToolbar(toolbar)
                .withHasStableIds(true)
                .withAccountHeader(headerResult) //set the AccountHeader we created earlier for the header
                .addDrawerItems(
                        new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Dokumentation").withDescription("mobile Office").withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_sun).withIdentifier(1).withSelectable(false),
                        new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName("Datenbank").withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_collection_case_play).withIdentifier(2).withSelectable(false)
                ) // add the items we want to use with our Drawer
                .withOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onItemClick(View view, int position, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {
                        //check if the drawerItem is set.
                        //there are different reasons for the drawerItem to be null
                        //--> click on the header
                        //--> click on the footer
                        //those items don't contain a drawerItem

                        if (drawerItem != null) {
                            Intent intent = null;
                            if (drawerItem.getIdentifier() == 1) {
                                displayView(0);
                            } else if (drawerItem.getIdentifier() == 2) {

                                if (opened) {
                                    //remove the items which are hidden
                                    result.removeItems(2000, 2001, 2002, 2003);
                                } else {
                                    int curPos = result.getPosition(drawerItem);
                                    result.addItemsAtPosition(
                                            curPos,
                                            new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName("Anlage").withLevel(2).withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_8tracks).withIdentifier(2000),
                                            new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName("Maschine").withLevel(2).withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_8tracks).withIdentifier(2001),
                                            new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName("Eigenschaften").withLevel(2).withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_8tracks).withIdentifier(2002),
                                            new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName("Werte").withLevel(2).withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_8tracks).withIdentifier(2003)
                                    );
                                }
                                opened = !opened;
                                return true;
                            } else if (drawerItem.getIdentifier() == 2000) {

                            } else if (drawerItem.getIdentifier() == 2001) {

                            } else if (drawerItem.getIdentifier() == 2002) {

                            } else if (drawerItem.getIdentifier() == 2003) {


                    }
                })
                .withSavedInstance(savedInstanceState)
                .withShowDrawerOnFirstLaunch(true)
                .build();

        RecyclerViewCacheUtil.getInstance().withCacheSize(2).init(result);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            //result.setSelection(1, false);

            //set the active profile
            headerResult.setActiveProfile(profile2);
        }

        result.updateBadge(2, new StringHolder(10 + ""));
    }

    private void displayView(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new FragmentAnlage();
                title = "Anlage";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
        }
    }

}
```

my gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.stack.overflow"
            minSdkVersion 21
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
        compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:4.6.4@aar') {
            transitive = true
        }
        compile 'com.mikepenz:google-material-typeface:2.2.0.1@aar'
        compile 'com.mikepenz:fontawesome-typeface:4.4.0.1@aar'
        compile 'com.mikepenz:octicons-typeface:3.0.0.1@aar'
    }
```

Comment: you are mixing two types of code into one

Comment: So it seems that I have misunderstood something. Can you explain me the issue, please?

Comment: Your display view method is from AndroidHive website and you are using navigation drawer template provide by android studio right?

Comment: and you are not even using that library that you are pointing to

Comment: I am using the navigation drawer that you can get using that dependency: com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:4.6.4@aar . And yes, the display view method is from AndroidHive

Comment: so android hive tutorial doesn't uses coordinator layout. It uses drawer layout for creating navigation drawer. Just follow any one way not mix them up

Comment: yes, I am using the library that I am pointing to. But it is possible to implement it just in MainActivity - Should I post it? My problem is, that the navigation drawer library I use does not contain any sample with content fragments

Comment: yes post it and your gradle too

Comment: This library code is too complicated to understand. I would suggest you to follow Android Hive tutorial as I have experience problem with navigation drawer when creating using co-ordinator layout

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a nice video that explains and shows how to use a navigation drawer with fragments, including the code:

[YouTube Video: Android Tutorial 9 - The Navigation Drawer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5b6AGSh4dVE)

Comment: Thank you. I will follow your video if I will not find any solution. Is there really no possibility how to use content fragments with that library? It is fast and offers some nice features I would like to use

Comment: I am not familiar with the library you use. But the video will explain clearly how to use fragments through the fragment manager which is used by default by most apps. It is really not that complicated once you see an example.